# How to link two html pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So i'm working on a chat application and i want to add smileys. So i used two html pages. the first one contain the text area when we wright the messages and an iframe that references the second html page.

```
<div class="col-12">
   <textarea  class="col-12 row-12 var_MessageInput" id="textmsg" placeholder="Write a reply..."></textarea>
</div>
```

in the second html page i have smiley images

```
<img src="../../../images/sad_smile.gif"   onclick="insertSmiley('sad');"/>
<img src="../../../images/angel_smile.gif" onclick="insertSmiley('angel');"/>
<img src="../../../images/happy_smile.gif" onclick="insetSmiley('happy');" />
```

So i want that when i click at a smiley image that a text got inserted in my text area so i used the following script

```
function insertSmiley(smiley) {
  var currentText = document.getElementById("textmsg");
  var smileyWithPadding = " " + smiley + " ";
  currentText.value += smileyWithPadding;
  currentText.focus();
}
```

But it doens't work :( i thought the problem might be in document.getElementById since it's another html page but i have no idea how to solve it. 
Thanks a lot

Comment: Try `parent.document.getElementById("textmsg");`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but still it doesn't work.

Comment: Do you get any error in console? On what page is the function `insertSmiley`. Did you check the debugger, does it hit the function? Can you add complete code for both files i.e parent and iframe or may be setup a fiddle

Comment: in the log i get Uncaught ReferenceError: insertSmiley is not defined. the insertSmiley function is defined in a emoticone.js file. i added references to that file in both html pages

Comment: You should add your complete code in order to get some help.

Comment: i added the whole code of the first html page. the others are already complete. in emoticone.js i have only the function InsertSmiley(smiley). and in the chatApp_emoticons.html i have the three images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Have you included the `<script src="Scripts_Chatapp/emoticone.js"></script>` in iframe too? If yes, remove the script reference from iFrame.
2. Move the script reference  `<script src="Scripts_Chatapp/emoticone.js"></script>` at top of page with other script tags.
3. Change the `onclick="insertSmiley('sad');"` TO `onclick="parent.insertSmiley('sad');"`.

This will call the parent function and make changes on that page, since element exists on parent.

Comment: @Chaymae If the issue is solved, please mark an answer

Answer (score 0):

You have one typo in `onclick="insetSmiley('happy');"` it should be `onclick="insertSmiley('happy');"`. I checked it and it works for me.

Comment: Thanks i've corrected it. But it's still not working for me :(

Comment: i think he meant that i forgot an "r" in my insertSmiley at the third line

Comment: check the browser log

Comment: i get  Uncaught ReferenceError: insertSmiley is not defined even if i added the reference to the javascript file in both html pages

Comment: maybe reference to js file is incorrect? and also imgs need to be in the same file with textarea

Answer (score 0):

In your JS code, use:

```
window.location = "second_HTML_Page.html" ;
```

Comment: Let me get this straight, Are you saying that for example this frame doesn't reference the html page: <iframe class="hidden" id="iOneConversation" src="templates/ChatApp_OneConversation.html"></iframe>? Meaning the "ChatApp_OneConversation.html" is not being shown in the main HTML page?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when the function is triggered within the iFrame, the scopes become complicated.

A solution would be to make the function *global* by defining it at the `window` level.  And then when the function is to be triggered inside the iFrame, it can call the function of the iFrame's parent (the main window).

Example Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/e37rrtb1/2/

Comment: Thanks, i tried your answer but it gives me this error ChatApp_Interface_gridLayout.html:1 Uncaught TypeError: window.parent.insertSmiley is not a function

Comment: Is the function defined as `window.insertSmiley = function(smiley) { ...` in the *parent* window? (i.e. the emoticone.js should be included in the main window, and inside the file, the function should be defined with the `window.`)